# Can't find button inside a *ngIf statement while testing because statement involves a mocked class

Tags: angular, testing

I'm building an application where people can authenticate with Github in Angular. I've build a button to do so. When trying to test this button, the test doesn't seem to find the button. I think it has to do something with the *ngIf statement.

login.component.spec.ts:

```
    class MockAuthService implements Partial<AuthService> {
  isAuthenticated() {
    return 'Mocked';
  }


  loginwithGithubProvider() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());
  }

  logout(): Promise<boolean | Observable<never> | never> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(); });
  }
}


describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let componentService: AuthService;
  const routerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);
  const ghServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GithubService', ['methodName']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatCardModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
        RouterModule.forRoot([{path: '', component: LoginComponent}]),
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        AngularFirestore,
        AngularFireAuth,
        HttpClient,
        HttpHandler
      ]
    });
    TestBed.overrideComponent(LoginComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          {provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService},
          {provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy},
          {provide: GithubService, useValue: ghServiceSpy},
        ]
      }
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AuthService);
  }));

  it('Logginbutton calls signInWithGithub', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'signInWithGithub');
    const button =  fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#signInWithGithub');
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.signInWithGithub).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));
```

login.component.html:

```
 <div *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn; else loginTemplate">
    <h1>Welcome {{authService?.username}}</h1>
    <img src="{{ authService?.userDetails?.photoURL }} ">
    <br />
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn-github" id="logout" (click)="logout()">
      <i class="fab fa-github"></i> Stop authentication Github
    </button>
  </div>

  <ng-template #loginTemplate>
    <h1>FullProjectCloner</h1>
    <button mat-flat-button class="btn-github" id="signInWithGithub" (click)="signInWithGithub()">
      <i class="fab fa-github"></i> Authenticate with github
    </button>
    <p class="authError">{{this?.loginError}}</p>
  </ng-template>
```

The error i get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

Comment: Well yeah, return false in your condition ...

Comment: @trichetriche Ah i forgot to delete the part 'isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return true;
  }'. The isLoggedIn() function always returns false right now.

Comment: Well now you have deleted it. What do you really have ? Also, in your template it's a variable/getter, not a function, like your mock declared it.

Comment: @trichetriche 'isLoggedIn()' always returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you have set everything up, but not invoked the lifecycle changes necessary to have Angular actually render anything before you are testing it.

Simple fix is to invoke `fixture.detectChanges()` after you spyOn the component.

I put this together in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53850889?file=app%2Flogin.component.spec.ts) to be sure it would work for you.  In that Stackblitz simply comment out the `fixture.detectChanges()` and you will see the issue.

Here is the spec from that Stackblitz:

```
it('Logginbutton calls signInWithGithub', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'signInWithGithub');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const button =  fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#signInWithGithub');
  button.click();
  expect(component.signInWithGithub).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

You will notice I also removed the call to `whenStable()` as that also is not needed.

Comment: This really helped me out. Thanks a lot!